# highcharts json tooltip created in python

Tags: python, json, highcharts

I am trying to set up the whole highcharts dataset within my python code:
All is fine except for my knowledge how to add the tool-tip function to my json object. (or create a python function that can be converted?)

At the moment I set up a dict that I later render to json.

```
def monthly_balance_default(characterapi):
    dataset = defaultdict(dict)
    dataset['title']['useHTML'] = True
    dataset['title']['text'] = "<i>ISK balance last 30 days</i>"
    dataset['credits']['enabled'] = False
    etc...

    return json.dumps(dataset)
```

however I cant figure out how to add my tool-tip which in javascript would look something like this

```
tooltip: {
    formatter: function() {
        return Highcharts.dateFormat('%e. %b %Y', new Date(this.x))
         + "<br>" + numeral(this.y).format('0,0') + " mil ISK" ;
    }
},
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction on how I can also add the tool-tip function to my json object

Comment: Generally in the JSON you cannot set functions, because it not will be executed.

Comment: Do you have any other idea how i could keep this part within my code? (instead of adding it later in javascript itself)?

Comment: Im sorry Im not familiar with python, but maybe wrapper prepared by third party developers, will be helpful (http://chartit.shutupandship.com) ?